# Unable to set public static IP ubuntu 18.04.1 amd 64 during install

Tags: networking, server, ip

I am trying to install 18.04.1. I have a block of 8 static IP addresses from my isp. My subnet is 255.255.255.248/29 when i input my static IP (using 192.168.0.x for example and lets assume my network number is .40) 192.168.0.45 the installer tells me that the IP address is not in 255.255.255.248/29. This may be a noobish question, but what am i missing?

The settings work on my windows based servers

i'm successfully using 3 of the 5 available IPs (with the .40 network number .46 is specified as the gateway by my isp leaving .41-.45 available as my public ip addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up notation method, and using a subnet mask as your subnet definition. You should define your subnet as 192.168.0.40/29.

Comment: Thanks! i have very little experience with linux